# Recursion while data not received

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

How run download and parse the same url, while needed data not received, or call of recursion is > 5 times?

For example i need get h1 from example.com, but server return different pages: with h1, and without it. I want that the code run download and parse url while h1 not get or recursion call > 5 times.

For example

```
import re
from kupito.items import KupitoItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class idpkzSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'idp.kz'
allowed_domains = ['idp.kz']
start_urls = [
    'http://idp.kz/index.php/katalog-tovarov/monitors'
]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*start=\d+$')), callback='parse_start_url', follow=True),
)

def parse_start_url(self, response):

    items = []

    hxs = Selector(response)
    dirEl = hxs.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()
    goods = hxs.xpath('//div[@class=\'jshop list_product\']/div[@class=\'block_product\']')

    if dirEl and len(goods) > 0:
        dirName = dirEl[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
        for good in goods:
            name = good.xpath('div//div[@class=\'name\']/a/text()').extract()
            price = good.xpath('div//div[@class=\'jshop_price\']/span/text()').extract()
            url = good.xpath('div//div[@class=\'name\']/a/@href').extract()
            if name and price and url:
                item = KupitoItem()
                item['name'] = name[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
                item['price'] = price[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
                item['url'] = url[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
                item['dirName'] = dirName
                items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: what have you done so far ?? Any code sample ??

Comment: I add my sample code, i need try download and parse page maximum 3 times if no data (if NOT dirEl OR len(goods) == 0)